# How to have an Android Cursor return multiples values from a row with multiple columns with one loop iteration?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I am creating an app that uses an SQLite Database. I have 3 columns description, grade, and weight. I want to iterated through these values and save an instance of each in a list.

Right now I am looping through my database like this:

```java
public List<Entry> populateList(){

    List<Entry> gradeWeightList = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    Calc_db openClass = new Calc_db(this);
    openClass.read();

    //Cursor required to read database query
    Cursor cursor = openClass.getBd().query(Calc_db.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String dbDescipt = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calc_db.COLUMN_GRADE_VALUE));
        Double dbGrade = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calc_db.COLUMN_GRADE_VALUE));
        Double dbWeight = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Calc_db.COLUMN_WEIGHT_VALUE));
        Entry e1 = new Entry (dbDescipt, dbGrade, dbWeight);
        gradeWeightList.add(e1);    
    }

    cursor.close();
    openClass.close();

    return gradeWeightList;
}
```

In order to get all three column values I am having to keep track of how many loops have occurred so I know I have all the data from 1 row. (I have commented out most of that because I feel that it is a bad way to do it). It appears to be looping through each column one at a time. Therefore 3 loops occurs in order to get all the data from 1 row.

Is there a way to return all the data  from 1 row within 1 loop. This way for each row I could make a new instance of the class that encapsulates my grade data (`GradeEntry()`) set its properties, and add it to my list of type `GradeEntry()`.

This is how I am inserting data:

```java
public void addEntry(Entry marks){

    try{
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION_VALUE, marks.getDESCRIPT());
        values.put(COLUMN_GRADE_VALUE, marks.getGRADE());
        values.put(COLUMN_WEIGHT_VALUE, marks.getWEIGHT());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: One loop = one row. How are you inserting the data?

Comment: I've attached my insert method. I am confused about how to get all the column values from one row at once.

Comment: Your code (without the `count` stuff) looks correct. Why do you think that it isn't? Don't you get all three values in each loop?

Comment: I realized my issue wasn't in this code. When retrieving my data, I was looping through incorrectly which is why it appear the cursor was not looping through the columns correctly.  THANKS!